# Adding functions to GUI in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I used [simpletab.m from MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15193-simple-tab-panel/content/simpletab.m) to make simple tabs in GUI Matlab, now I wanted to add another function so that the result of the added function is displayed when I press the GUI tab buttons.

For example I want to add a function to every tab, when I press "tab 1" that function output (in this case a graph) is displayed.

**Update 1**

*THANKS FOR YOUR PROMPT REPLY.*
It worked good, but what if I don't want to the "Tab 1 function" to appear when I press the Tab button..straight away I want my graphs to be properly listed when I press tab 1 button.

**Update 2**

I have written the modified function that you told me but still I get the tab name 'Tab 1 function' when I press the tab 1 button.

Moreover I want **two** sub tabs to appear straight under the tab 1 button when I press the tab 1 button..one sub tab will display data on one graph for all sensors and one tab will display data on individual graphs.

Do I have to write two separate functions and two separate subcall functions for each sub tab?

I hope you have understood what I am trying to say. I'm really running out of time..:(..feeling lost

Comment: Hello Khalid, welcome to Stack Overflow! When an answer is helpful, please don't say "Thanks" is your text - rather click the "up" arrow next to that answer to say "this was helpful" :-). Also, if an answer solves your problem, click on the checkmark to mark that answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your function to the appropriate callback (see end of file):

```
% --- Executes on button press in tab1button.
function tab1button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

figure();
plot(1:10);


% --- Executes on button press in tab2button.
function tab2button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

disp('Button from Tab 2 was pressed')
figure();
plot(11:20);


% --- Executes on button press in tab3button.
function tab3button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

figure();
plot(11:20);
```

Now, if you press tab2, you'll see the message 'Button from Tab 2 was pressed' AND a new figure will open with a line going from 11:20.
All you have to do now is to customize your plotting in the according callback function.

**EDIT:** I've modified 'tab1button_Callback' so that only the plotting function will be executed.

Comment: I am not been able to make this GUI using Guide.Can it be made with guide?.I am not been able to highlight tab 1 and its subtabs when i press it, otherwise all the subtabs of the tab2 and tab 3 are also displayed along side

Comment: no need for guide. just copy & paste the file as posted in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15193-simple-tab-panel/content/simpletab.m and modify the end of the file as shown in my post.

Comment: I have written the modified function that you told me but still I get the tab name 'Tab 1 function' when I press the tab 1 button.

Moreover I want two sub tabs to appear straight under the tab 1 button when I press the tab 1 button..one sub tab will display data on one graph for all sensors and one tab will display data on individual graphs.

Do I have to write two separate functions and two separate subcall functions for each sub tab?

I hope you have understood what I am trying to say. I'm really running out of time..:(..feeling lost..please feel free to advice and ask anything

Comment: any suggestions :(http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/july02/gui.html i have tried to implement this example but i cudnt do it